# SET NOCOUNT ON usage- correct position in SQL Server 2012 trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

My question concerns the correct positioning of `SET NOCOUNT ON` in a trigger- after a bit of Googling it's position relative to 'BEGIN' seems in dispute. 
We have multiple triggers similar to that below, one of which is still returning results to the application. Is the correct position for `SET NOCOUNT ON` immediately after '`BEGIN`'?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [scheme].[T_AD_IU_STOCKM] ON [scheme].[stockm]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF (update([alpha]) or update([catalogue_number]) or update([current_cost])       or update([description]) 
or update([expected_cost]) or update([long_description]) or update([physical_qty]) or update([price])
 or update([product]) or update([standard_cost]))

BEGIN
//Should 'SET NOCOUNT ON' be here?
    insert into Bespoke_JLA.dbo.MOD_STOCKM
    SELECT 
        distinct i.product, i.warehouse, getdate()
    FROM 
        inserted i
    WHERE 
        i.warehouse in ('PH', 'MH');
END

GO
```

Comment: By immediately after BEGIN do you mean before those other two SET operations? No it just has to be before anything that returns a 'rows affected' message. What do you mean by "returning results to the application"? Is it returning rows affected or a dataset?

Comment: Nick - no, I meant after 'BEGIN' but before the insert statement- I have added a comment to the original post to show exactly where. One of the 7 triggers on this table written with NOCOUNT ON in the same place is returning the rows affected under some circumstance but not every time and having already removed one trigger at a time and thinking i had narrowed it to one it still happens

Comment: Since you are using triggers, is it possible that you have another trigger firing that you don't expect, or the rows affected is coming from the actual operation that fires the trigger

Comment: They are possibilities i have already looked into. By the look of the link from Kavin below using the example trigger as is should work so I will continue to investigate other things. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Use SET NOCOUNT statement at the start of the trigger to prevent the return of any result sets.**

For More Details See **Trigger Limitations** Block in the below MSDN Link
[Trigger Limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Kavin, from your link it looks like it should work correctly as is